# .NET Authorization Handler running before middleware

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to add in authorization middleware which sets the user in a dependency injected interface. I have tested this and is successful.

I then wanted to add a authorization handler which checks the users role vs the role which is expected, for example to limit certian actions of the api to superusers.

I've created the authorization handler which is here, as you can see I'm dependency injecting the `IUserProvider`, the authenticated user is set within the middleware of this method.

```
public class RoleHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RoleRequirement>, IAuthorizationHandler
{
    private readonly IUserProvider _userProvider;

    public RoleHandler(IUserProvider userProvider)
    {
        _userProvider = userProvider;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        var currentUser = _userProvider.GetAuthenticatedUser();
            
        if (requirement.Roles.Contains(currentUser.RoleId))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

AuthenticationMiddleware:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IUserRepository userRepository, IUserProvider userProvider, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    var email = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "preferred_username");

    if (email == null)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        return;
    }

    var user = await userRepository.FindByEmailAsync(email.Value);

    if (user == null)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        return;
    }

    userProvider.SetAuthenticatedUser(user);

    await _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

I can see that the AuthorizationHandler is getting called before the AuthorizationMiddleware which is why this is occuring.

However, I've tried to check the context within the `HandleRequirementAsync` and the user in here is also null.

Here is my user provider, as you can see very basic:

```
public class UserProvider : IUserProvider
{
    private static User AuthenticatedUser { get; set; } = default!;

    public User GetAuthenticatedUser()
    {
        return AuthenticatedUser;
    }

    public void SetAuthenticatedUser(User user)
    {
        AuthenticatedUser = user;
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to alter the execution order?

EDIT:

Forgot to add in the controller where I am using this:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Superuser")]
[Route("{id}"]
public async Task<User> UpdateAsync([FromBody] User user, int id)
{
    return await _userService.UpdateAsync(user);
}
```

And the Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDataAccessLayer();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")).EnableSensitiveDataLogging().EnableDetailedErrors();
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, RoleHandler>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Superuser", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new RoleRequirement(Role.SUPER_USER)));
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: The order of the steps you invoke on `app` is the actual order of the request pipeline. Before any further deep dives, in your `Program.cs`, you're calling `app.UseAuthorization()` before your middleware -- what happens if you invert those two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to solve the opposite problem; the middleware was running before my `AuthorizationHandler`s.

To get the authorization middleware to run after the authorization attributes have run, create a class that implements the `IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler` interface as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse).

---

Additional notes:

For anyone else that wasted an afternoon and stumbles across this answer looking for a way to get the custom authorization middleware to run after your [resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (after you call the `AuthorizeAsync` method), you can't. You will either need to use middleware or a [result filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#result-filters).